# Pandas dataframe: add time to date+time column if time does no exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have two column in a pandas dataframe. First column is time+date and second column is price. But when it comes to 00:00:00 on a new day the time is omitted. How can I add 00:00:00 back to those cell which doesn't have time? I have tried splitting the cell by a space but it doesn't work since those cell in question doesn't have space. Thanks a lot

Now:

```
           datetime  Price
29.11.2018 16:00:00  05929
29.11.2018 17:00:00  05922
30.11.2018           05345
01.12.2018           05325
```

What I want to achieve:

```
           datetime  Price
29.11.2018 16:00:00  05929
29.11.2018 17:00:00  05922
30.11.2018 00:00:00  05345
01.12.2018 00:00:00  05325
```

Comment: What is in those empty cells? An empty string? NaN?

Comment: The `'datetime'` column is probably filled with strings.  Try `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`.  Pandas will show the `00:00:00` when there exist non-zero time elements in other cells.

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime`. If that doesn't work, provide a [mcve].